# New Tab in Existing Frame of IE

Tags: internet-explorer, com, automation

Problem -
Want to launch a new IE tab inside existing IE Frame with correct 'integrity level'. 
Like what IELaunchURL() does, it gets us new instance of IE with correct integrity level.

What I am doing currently ?
Detecting IWebBrowser2 for existing IEFrame, then calling IWebBrowser2->Navigate2() with the URL. Struck in getting IWebBrowser2 for the newly launched tab

Comment: Could you be more precise? What is the problem to solve?

Comment: IELaunchURL() from MS opens a given URL in a new frame or new window every time I call it. I want to open an URL as a tab in IE (not in new window).

Comment: In other words we have a tab running inside IE frame, and I want to get IWebBrowser2 ptr to this tab, all I know it the URL of the tab.

Comment: What? You question is "how to get IWebBroser2?" ??? Your question is realy badly worded.

Comment: What is the programming language?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience .. I want to enumerate all open TABS in IE along with their IWebBrowser2 ptrs

Comment: I am working on the lines of -http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/e3a501d6-2163-4cc0-be2d-5011e7fa9613/interacting-wtabs-in-ie7?forum=ieextensiondevelopment

Comment: Ok, let me know if you have a question about the link, then.

Comment: I want to fix the integrity level of TAB at the instant I am launching it. Right now, by default I get TAB with low integrity level which gets replaced by medium integrity tab when non-protected URL is opened. This TAB swap invalidates IWebBrowser2 which I have.

Comment: Are you really sure you have a valid IWebBrowser2 for the new tab, before it is "invalidated"? How do you get it?

Comment: Background - Get IWebBrowser2 ptr for IEFrame & call Navigate2() to create new tab. After this - again, I am enumerating all shell windows on the screen and then casting them to IWeBrowser2 so this is supposed to give me IWebBrowser2 ptr to each of the TABS and IEFrame. Now the task the remains is finding which IWebBrowser2 of all we have belongs to the new TAB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use navOpenInNewTab (0x0800) in parameter "Flags" of the IWebBrowser2::Navigate2 method.

Beware, you must pass a Variant of type VT_I4.

Doc: [Navigate2 method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752094.aspx)

If you want to get the IWebBrowser2 interface pointer for the new Tab, just do as you have done to get the first one. Many ways available.

If you just get all IWebBrowser2 by some sort of enumeration, you could detect the new one by retrieving the URL (IHTMLDocument2::get_URL)

If the URL criteria is not enough, you could cache the list of the windows hosting the IWebBroser2 objects (IWebBrowser2 ==> QueryInterface for IServiceProvider, IServiceProvider ==> QueryService for IOleWindow, IOleWindow ==> GetWindow)

Those windows have a "TabWindowClass" (with Internet Explorer 9... YOUR mileage may vary). If you build a new list of IWebBrowser2, the one hosted by a new tab window, is the new tab :-)

Comment: Thank you so much :) .. I will implementing couple of ways including the one you suggested here .. I will like to share some observations & get back with any queries I have.

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977066/search-match-ie-tab-to-get-iwebbrowser2-which-of-these-is-best-why

Comment: Added the above link since the data was huge .. please let me know your opinion

Comment: // compare title with expected title
Can above lines be replaced by IWebBrowser2->get_HWND(&hwnd) & GetWindowText(hwnd) - This will give me IEFram Window - Sorry